# Jenkins can't connect to a database during a unit test after a build

Tags: database, ant, junit, hudson, jenkins

I'm moving my ant build to a new Jenkins server. It can access SVN, compile and all that.  Everything is great until it starts running unit tests.  A few of the tests need access to a database to be able to execute.

I've logged into the server that Jenkins runs from, and by using telnet on the database port, I can tell that the path is open.  (The IT guys also say the path is open).  I know it's a database issue because I can reproduce the issue locally when I mess up the config file so the build cannot find the database.

My problem is this.  I really need Jenkins to tell me why it can't connect to the database.  I have not been able to figure out how to do this.  The console output simply shows it trying the test forever.  Any and all suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is trying to access the database? If it's a unit test, why can't you add some logging in there? What happens when you run the tests on your local machine (through Jenkins, you can install it locally)?

Comment: You bring up two very good points.  Let me look into those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you pass the DB parameters from Ant to the junit target? If so, add the `-v` parameter to the ant build step in your jenkins config to get extra logging & therefore see what DB parameters are being set.

Alternatively, do your tests load the DB parameters themselves? Depending on how they are read, you may have a classpath or path issue. In this case, log the path, classpath and any other relevant variables in your test.

Keep in mind that the junit task has a `timeout` parameter you can set if you don't want it to hang forever.

Finally, you can log onto the jenkins host and trigger a thread dump from the executing test. This is done by sending a `kill -3` signal to the java process (on *nix) or, if you are running jenkins on windows and your JVM is not too old you can execute [jstack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html). The resulting stack trace (which should appear in the Jenkins build log) may lead to some insight.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it has a lot of good debugging techniques.  My problem was actually very simple.  The configuration file needed a fully qualified domain name since the Jenkins server moved into a new environment where the DB was no longer on the same network.  We have different config files for different environments, and I edited the wrong one the first time which is why I got to the point where I posted on here.  Once I edited the right file, it worked flawlessly.